# Inside docker, with user, connect to docker daemon

Tags: docker

In a Dockerfile,

```
RUN apt-get update ; apt-get install -y docker.io ; apt-get clean
RUN newgrp docker
RUN adduser --disabled-password --uid ${UID} --ingroup docker --gecos '' test
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I try to use the docker inside the container.
I run with:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

with root:

... -u 0

I can call `docker ps`

With the user

... -u 1000

I can't

```
   $ id
   uid=1000(test) gid=107(docker) groups=107(docker)
   $ docker ps
    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at  unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get    http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix    /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The use is in the group 'docker'.
How I can resolve that?

Comment: The group needs to have the same numeric group ID as owns the socket file.  It doesn't matter if the host group and the container group are both named `docker` if they have different group IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the external docker group

```
docker run \
    --user 1000 \
    --group-add $(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    ...
```